# Sum of Digits in a String (using string objects) C++

Tags: c++, string, object, sum, c-strings

I am currently trying to take a user input string of digits, convert them individually into an int, and total their sum.

EX: If user enters "1234", program should do 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 and display "10". I have tried experimenting a lot but seem to be at a stand still.

I'm looking to create this code using C-string/String objects, and with "istringstream()" if possible (not necessary though...[esp if there are easier ways...])

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string digits;
    int total = 0, num;

    cout << "Enter a string of digits, and something magical will happen to them..." << endl;
    cin >> digits;

    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++)
    {   
        cout << digits.at(i) << endl;
        istringstream(digits.at(i)) >> num;
        cout << num << endl;    // Displays what came out of function
        total += num;
    }

    cout << "Total: " << total << endl;

    // Digitize me cap'm
    // Add string of digits together
    // Display Sum
    // Display high/low int in string
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why do I keep getting super high numbers in the for loop? Are there more efficient functions I should be using? Thank you for any help :)

Comment: `istringstream(digits.at(i))` shouldn't even compile, what compiler / standard library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++)
{   
    cout << digits.at(i) << endl;
    num = digits.at(i) - '0';
    assert(0 <= num && num <= 9);
    cout << num << endl;    // Displays what came out of function
    total += num;
}
```

To convert a single number you don't need complex things like stringstream.
You can also use (not recommended) `istringstream(digits.substr(i, 1))`

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses (holy CRAP y'all respond fast)! I went with this - I think this is most what my prof is looking for. Thank you Mohit... Noob questions: Is that assert() 0-9 because it's a single digit we're reading? Also, what is the significance of putting a - '0'?

Comment: I am happy it worked for you. Assertion will just make sure that all the digits are in range `0-9` (and that input doesn't contain characters like a, b etc). `'0'` is the code of character `0` which may be different from zero. On most the codings (ANSI for example), code of 1, 2, 3 etc are in continuation. So subtracting `'0'` from a character would convert that character into required digit.

Comment: replacing `assert(0 <= num && num <= 9);` with `isdigit(num)` provides a better performance and a more concise code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of istringstream(digits.at(i)) >> num , try using this way of conversion :

```
num = ((int)digits.at(i))-((int) ('0'));
```

You will have a faster code alltogether.

Comment: That's doing far more casting than necessary, especially considering that you can do math with `char`. In the very unexpected case of `0` being bigger than any of the other digits, far more things would break anyway.

Comment: Bad habbits from workling on multiple languages / compilers . Sometimes explicit casts from char to int are required in order to avoid warnings / errors.

Comment: Ah I see, should typically only happen if you're assigning a potentially bigger value to a more narrow type though (e.g. from `int` to `char`).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new function for getting the digit sum of any number:

```
long long digitSum(long long number)
{
    long long sum = 0;
    while (number != 0)
    {
        sum += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

and then you can do in your main():

```
int main()
{
    string digits;

    cout << "Enter a string of digits, and something magical will happen to them..." << endl;
    cin >> digits;

    auto enteredNumber = std::stoll(digits);
    auto total = digitSum(enteredNumber);

    cout << "Total: " << total << endl;
}
```

The function [std::stoll](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) converts a `std::string` to `long long`

This will limit the number the user can enter, though. So another approach is, like other answers already said, to use the property of chars (that they are just a number).

The value of the char `'0'` is `48`. The value of the char `'1'` is `49`. so when you do `'1' - '0'` you get the result `1`, which is exactly the number value of the number in char representation.

This means you can do something like this:

```
long long digitSum(string numberStr)
{
    long long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberStr.length(); i++)
    { 
        auto charValue = numberStr.at(i) - '0';
        sum += charValue;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

which will make your main look like this:

```
int main()
{
    string digits;

    cout << "Enter a string of digits, and something magical will happen to them..." << endl;
    cin >> digits;

    auto total = digitSum(digits);

    cout << "Total: " << total << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a little knowledge about ASCII (if you don't know I'll explain in the comment section):

```
long long sumOfDigitsInString(string n)
{
    long long sum = 0; 
    for(char& c : n) // for each char in string n
    {
         int b = int(c)-48; // this is involved in ascii
         sum += b;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    string n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << sumOfDigitsInString(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I extend previous answers with two things. I recommend using `static_cast` before a regular cast with `(int)`. It is also good to ignore non-digit characters in a string to prevent crashes or wrong behavior. The final solution looks like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

long long sumOfDigitsInString(string digits)
{
    long long sum = 0; 
    for(auto& ch : digits)
    {
         if (isdigit(ch))
         {
            sum += static_cast<int>(ch) - 48;
         }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    string n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << sumOfDigitsInString(n);
}
```